# Publishing a web project with Team Foundation Server 2015 continuous integration workflow

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I've set up my automated builds in TFS, and I've been playing around with ways to do automated deployments. The problem I'm having at this point is that although I'm able to copy the build path's content to another machine, I'd like to actually just publish one of the solution's web projects to an IIS instance.

I can't find any tutorials or guidelines this specific. Is anyone familiar with this, or can at least point me in the right direction?

So far, the only steps on my build definition is the actual build, and a Windows Machine File Copy build step. I assume I'd probably need some scripts or perhaps some sort of a build argument to msbuild to publish? And even so, how would I instruct it to only publish a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

If you have muti projects in a solution, you just need to specify the publish profile name of the Project. For example, ProjA has a publish profile named ‘siteone – Web Deploy’, ProjB does not. When trying to publish this you may try the following command line.

```
msbuild.exe PublishOnlyOne.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=’siteone – Web Deploy’ /p:Password=%password%
```

More info for you reference from this link: [How to publish one web project from a solution](http://sedodream.com/2013/03/06/HowToPublishOneWebProjectFromASolution.aspx)